# Google Check MX email setup checker says: MTA STS is malformed

Tags: email, smtp, spf, dkim, dmarc

I have a new domain `ausset.au`.

I've set up all recommended email security features, like [SPF](https://support.google.com/a/answer/33786), [DKIM](https://support.google.com/a/answer/174124), [DMARC](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2466580), and [MTA-STS](https://support.google.com/a/answer/9261504).

When I check the setup with [MxToolbox](https://mxtoolbox.com/) everything [seems to be fine](https://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=mx%3Aausset.au), including [MTA-STS](https://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=mta-sts%3Aausset.au).

But when I use the [Check MX](https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/checkmx/) email setup checker from the [Google Admin Toolbox](https://toolbox.googleapps.com/) I always get the following [error message](https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/checkmx/check?domain=ausset.au&dkim_selector=):

```
If your domain wants to use MTA-STS (optional), the MTA-STS TXT record must comply with RFC8461.
MTA STS is malformed.
```

Here are all relevant DNS records:

##### A Records

| Type | Name | IPv4 address | TTL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | mta-sts.ausset.au. | 104.21.85.225 | 300 |
| A | mta-sts.ausset.au. | 172.67.211.221 | 300 |

##### MX Records

| Type | Name | Prio | Mail Server | TTL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| MX | ausset.au. | 1 | aspmx.l.google.com. | 3600 |
| MX | ausset.au. | 5 | alt1.aspmx.l.google.com. | 3600 |
| MX | ausset.au. | 5 | alt2.aspmx.l.google.com. | 3600 |
| MX | ausset.au. | 10 | alt3.aspmx.l.google.com. | 3600 |
| MX | ausset.au. | 10 | alt4.aspmx.l.google.com. | 3600 |

##### TXT Records

| Type | Name | Content | TTL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TXT | ausset.au. | "v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com -all" | 3600 |
| TXT | ausset.au. | "google-site-verification=xqVfNs...a4oIFds" [shortened for readability] | 3600 |
| TXT | _dmarc.ausset.au. | "v=DMARC1; p=reject; rua=mailto:dmarcrpt@ausset.au" | 1 |
| TXT | google._domainkey.ausset.au. | "v=DKIM1; k=rsa; p=MIIBIj...IDAQAB" [shortened for readability] | 1 |
| TXT | _mta-sts.ausset.au. | "v=STSv1; id=20230805184000" | 1 |
| TXT | _smtp._tls.ausset.au. | "v=TLSRPTv1; rua=mailto:tlsrpt@ausset.au,https://mta-sts.ausset.au/.well-known/mta-sts.txt" | 1 |

And that's the content of my MTA-STS policy file hosted under https://mta-sts.ausset.au/.well-known/mta-sts.txt:

```
version: STSv1
mode: testing
mx: aspmx.l.google.com
mx: *.aspmx.l.google.com
max_age: 604800
```

What am I doing wrong?

### Edit:

Now after adding another A record for the website, the Google Admin Toolbox Check MX fails completely, with `Check was not possible`.

But I have to say, I'm using Cloudflare and have a Cloudflare worker to host the MTA-STS policy and the website.

To be able to route traffic to a Cloudflare worker, you [need to have a bogus A record](https://community.cloudflare.com/t/setup-workers-on-personal-domain/88012/8) with the target in the `192.0.2.0/24` range, e.g. `192.0.2.1`.

So, my two real A records in the Cloudflare backend are:

| Type | Name | IPv4 address | TTL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | ausset.au. | 192.0.2.1 | 1 |
| A | mta-sts.ausset.au. | 192.0.2.1 | 1 |

However, I tested it without Cloudflare worker and hosted the MTA-STS policy on a web server with a real IP address, but got the exact same error message as mentioned above (`MTA STS is malformed`). So, I'm confident that it's not the Cloudflare worker setup.

Answer (score 3):

The difference between valid and invalid is very small.

I removed the whitespace after the ; and added a ; at the end. That fixed it for me. In other words try with:

```
TXT _mta-sts.ausset.au. "v=STSv1;id=20230805184000;"
TXT _smtp._tls.ausset.au. "v=TLSRPTv1;rua=mailto:tlsrpt@ausset.au;"
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried it, but unfortunately it didn't fix it for me. I even tried it with all the other TXT records, but still no luck. I'll try again tomorrow, maybe the records are just cached somewhere.

Comment: Just noticed, I think you need to remove this part: ",https://mta-sts.ausset.au/.well-known/mta-sts.txt". Edited my answer to reflect that

Comment: Thanks @MLK.
I deleted it, as you can see here:
https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/#TXT/_smtp._tls.ausset.au

But I still get the same error:
https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/checkmx/check?domain=ausset.au&dkim_selector=dkim

Comment: Grasping for straws, but from the first link it looks like the line is surrounded by quotes. Try removing those if that's the case

Comment: Thanks @MLK, but there are no quotes around it. Just checked Cloudflare. It's just the way the Google Admin Toolbox displays it.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this figured out in my case. Google wanted a tls reporting record. Once I got that added the error went away.

Example:
_smtp._tls.yourdomain.com.  14400   TXT
v=TLSRPTv1;rua=mailto:smtp-tls-reports@yourdomain.com;

Comment: Yes, I do have the same TXT record (as listed in my question above), but the Check MX tool from Google still fails for this domain.